# Using a variable and an id inside a querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I want to get value from the input column using querySelector. I need to use two id to get the correct column. The second id is stored in a variable and its an integer value. I have tried different things but I am not getting anything. Currently it gives me null.

```
 checkDescriptionField = document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+'descriptionFieldId'); 
 if(typeof checkDescriptionField !== 'undefined' && checkDescriptionField !== null)
        {
            descriptionFieldValue = document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+'descriptionFieldId').textContent; 
        }
```

The outer id is methodProperties and the inner is input id="0eca409e-e2f7-467d-bd5e-dff9b63e3715" and I want to get its value ="Customers"

```
<div id="methodProperties">
<td role="gridcell">
<input id="0eca409e-e2f7-467d-bd5e-dff9b63e3715" class="k-textbox gridTable propertiesField" value="Customers" readonly="" data-role="droptarget"   type="text">
<span class="errorTooltip" style="display: none;">
<span class="deleteTooltip" style="padding: 5px; display: inline;" title="Delete Value" data-role="tooltip">
</td>
```

I tried this but I get invalid error

```
checkDescriptionField = document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+descriptionFieldId); 
if(typeof checkDescriptionField !== 'undefined' && checkDescriptionField !== null)
        {
            descriptionFieldValue = document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+descriptionFieldId).textContent; 
        }
```

Comment: See @gurvinder372's answer. This has nothing to do with jQuery btw.

Comment: there are duplicates column with same id

Comment: @Masood That's so wrong **because** IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Doesn't matter, still nothing to do with jQuery. Bad html structure... only use id's once.

Comment: Additionally, you're trying to add the variable not as a variable but as a string.  Rather than this: `document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+'descriptionFieldId'); ` you should be doing this `document.querySelector('#methodProperties input#'+descriptionFieldId); `

Comment: i didn't made the structure so unfortunately I cannot change it.I have to live with it

Comment: And btw, you have a `td` as direct child of a `div`, still invalid!!! Who for the sake of God write this HTML markup?!....  If a coworker, tell your boss to fire him before he burns the office

Comment: @anied it gives an error because it the variable is starting with an integer

Comment: its a long code I just pasted a small portion. its not directly under div

Comment: @Masood: What I'm saying is that you aren't adding the variable, you're adding the string of the variable name.  If `var descriptionFieldId = 41`, then `'#methodProperties input#'+descriptionFieldId` will evaluate to "#methodProperties input#41" but `'#methodProperties input#'+'descriptionFieldId'` (what you have) will evaluate to "#methodProperties input#descriptionFieldId".

Comment: oh thanks I tried that first it gave an error

Comment: @anied can you please suggest something SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: everyone is so quick to criticize. I can not change any thing in the front end and I just posted part of code so people could understand what I want.

Comment: @Masood -- Hard to say-- probably that variable is not defined as you think it is.  You'll probably want to see what line it is breaking at and debug to see what the value is set as and go from there.

Answer (score 5):

> The outer id is methodProperties and the inner is input
>   id="0eca409e-e2f7-467d-bd5e-dff9b63e3715" and I want to get its value
>   ="Customers"

Try this

```
descriptionFieldValue = document.querySelector( '#' + descriptionFieldId ).value;
```

or since there is only one input in a `methodProperties`

```
descriptionFieldValue = document.querySelector( '#methodProperties input' ).value;
```

If you want to repeat the id, then use data-id attribute instead

```
<div data-id="methodProperties">
  <td role="gridcell">
    <input value="customers">
  </td>
</div>
```

and js as

```
descriptionFieldValue = document.querySelector( 'div[data-id="methodProperties"] input' ).value;  //this will take the value from first methodProperties
```

Comment: there are duplicates colmn with same id but there outer div is different so I need to use outer div

Comment: there are more than 1 input column I just posted a snip of code

Comment: @Masood you can assign a class to that required input and use that in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `document.querySelector(...).value` instead of `.textContent`. This way you can access the value of the input field.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0h0ajdb/